# What is the standard way of Incorporating Jasmine in Enyo Applications

Tags: karma-jasmine, enyo

I have been trying to incorporate `Jasmine` Test descriptions in my `Enyo` Applications. Is there any standard way to do this ?

**Edit: Forgive me, I should ask for A workable way instead of a "standard" way. Neither of the sites have enough docs on this thing.**

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'll only be testing your models and other such non-UI logic with Jasmine.  What you'll want to do is create a test suite that loads Jasmine and the Enyo framework.  Then, in your tests you'll create the necessary Enyo objects on the fly.  The Enyo team uses [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) for our testing and you can take a look at the `enyo/tools/mocha-tests` directory to see how we incorporated unit tests for the framework.

For UI testing you'll want to look at something like [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/) or [WD.js](https://github.com/admc/wd)